# Have to restart Firefox

Tags: sound, firefox, 17.10

I'm having some problems with the dreaded loss of sound in Firefox. The funny thing though is that it's only the first time I start Firefox that I'm affected by this issue. If I restart it, everything works fine.

Still though, it's a bit annoying so is there any way to make it work right away?

I'm on Ubuntu 17.10 (mini.iso) and currently running Firefox `59.0.2`

Comment: I'm now on the latest version. Purging Firefox and reinstalling it helped for a while but now I'm back to no sound at all, even after restarting firefox

Comment: What is the output of `amixer` when you are having the sound problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve my problem by installing the Firefox 60 beta from [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~mozillateam/+archive/ubuntu/firefox-next).

Sound seems to work fine so far.

Answer (score 0):

you don't have to re-installing it, did you try to *reset* Firefox? just open Firefox and click *Help* --> *Troubleshooting Information* and *click* **refresh Firefox** then it should load as a freshly installed *Firefox browser*

Other thing, after upgrades or whatsoever some *add-ons* can cause the issues then try *Step 2* and load *Firefox* with **disabled** *add-ons* once it worked you have to *disable* your *add-ons* one by one to figure it out which one is causing a lag.

[image]

Comment: let me know it it works

Comment: Thanks! I managed to solve my problem by upgrading to the latest beta version